# I have a method to download a mp3 file and save it, the method works fine and the percent works (sorta)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, mp3

This method for downloading a mp3 file works, and printing out the percent works as well, but I want to be able to change a label and I wont work all that happens is the file downloads while printing out the percent downloaded but not when trying to change the label. What am I doing wrong?

```
func download_Songs(){
    var request = HTTPTask()
    let downloadTask = request.download(urlText, parameters: nil, progress: {(complete: Double) in
           var a:String = String(format: "%f", complete)
        self.PlaySong.titleLabel?.text = a
        println("percent complete: \(a)")
        }, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
            println("download finished!")
            if response.responseObject != nil {
                //we MUST copy the file from its temp location to a permanent location.
                if let url = response.responseObject as? NSURL {
                    if let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as? String {
                        if let fileName = response.suggestedFilename {
                            if let newPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(path)/\(fileName)") {
                                let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                                fileManager.removeItemAtURL(newPath, error: nil)
                                fileManager.moveItemAtURL(url, toURL: newPath, error:nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } ,failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
            println("failure")
    })
}
```

[Link to HTTPSwift (used for the download_Songs function)](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP)

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnectionDataDelegate is what you should look for

Comment: Please provide links to documentation to support your answer as well as a brief demo of how to use it. Thanks.